# Symbol for "such that" (not in set)

Tags: symbols

If `a` is a set

```
a \leftarrow { b| b must satisfies property}
```

but if `a` is an element

```
a \leftarrow b| b must satisfies property
```

is this a usual notation? Or what other symbol should I use for the "such that" (`|`) symbol?

Comment: You can use `\mid`.

Comment: I have never seen such a notation, and it is confusing, too: what happens when there are several b that satisfy the condition? Which one gets assigned to a?

Comment: As egreg points out, `\mid` seems to be a good choice. Otherwise, you can try and find the symbol using either Detexify (http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) or the Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List (http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

Comment: If you really ask about a _mathematical notation_ and not about a _way how to typeset it in (La)TeX_, you should better ask on [math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com) ;)

Comment: @Werner It is not really an exact duplicate as it also asks for a typographical convention.

Comment: @mafp, then how would you do in such case to represent the "such that"?

Comment: @Werner yes, mafp is right.

Comment: @SvendMortensen The problem is I am not sure which symbol is suitable

Comment: @william007: In that sense, the question about symbol usage and suitability in the context that you're after, *is* more suitable on [math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @william007 You first have to define how you make the assignment well defined, i.e., how do you ensure that exactly one b is selected. If, e.g., you chose a minimal b, then `a \leftarrow \argmin \{b \mid b\text{ fulfils } P\}` would do.